# ¿Cómo puedo poner un enlace a una clase de Java en los comentarios?

Tags: java, javadoc

Estoy escribiendo la documentación de un proyecto y quisiera poner un enlace a una clase de Java en los comentarios.

Si hago esto:

```
/**
    Obtiene la fecha de Pascua de un año dado.
    Se usa el algoritmo de <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcul_de_la_date_de_P%C3%A2ques">Butcher-Meeus</a>
    @param theYear El año cuyo calendario se quiere generar
    @return Un objeto {@link Celebration} con la fecha de Pascua en formato yyyymmdd
 */
```

Cuando genero el JavaDoc el enlace que pongo aquí `{@link Celebration}` funciona perfectamente, porque `Celebration` es una clase de mi proyecto.

Ahora bien, el objeto que retorna el método anotado es del tipo `LocalDate` (que es una clase de Java) y yo quiero que haya un enlace a dicha clase.

He intentando de varias formas y ninguna funciona:

- `{@link LocalDate}`
- `{@link LocalDate LocalDate.class}`

Así funciona:

```
    @return Un objeto <a href="https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html"><code>LocalDate</code></a> con la fecha de Pascua en formato yyyymmdd
```

Pero quisiera saber si hay una forma más simple de hacerlo cuando se trata de clases propias de Java.

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, hacía falta el "fullPath" de la clase, en este caso `java.time.LocalDate`. Hace mucho que no lo hago así que puedo estar equivocado (o que haga falta algo más que no recuerdo). Un saludo y ya me cuentas si funciona!

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, @Benito-B. Lo he puesto así: `{@link java.time.LocalDate}` y también así: `{@link java.time.LocalDate LocalDate}`  y en ambos casos no funciona. En el doc generado me muestra la palabra `LocalDate` con formato `code` pero sin enlace.

Comment: Intenta con [@see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#@see)

Comment: @Sal gracias por la sugerencia. He probado con `@see LocalDate` y con `@see java.time.LocalDate` y en ambos casos me muestra un `See Also: LocalDate` pero **sin enlace a dicha clase**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para referencia a documentación externa tienes dos opciones:

1. Agregar la URL con [`@see`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#@see):

```
@see <a href="https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html">LocalDate</a>
```

2. Nombrar la clase y ligar el recurso externo con la opción [`- link`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link) en
   *Other Command Line arguments*: `-link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api`

```
{@link String} o {@link java.time.LocalDate}
@see java.lang.String
```

Comment: Hice lo que indicas en la opción `2` y ahora sí funciona. Muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

En [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) para agregar un enlace a una clase puedes usar

```
@see com.mypackage.Class#method()
```

Esta es la documentación:

> [Javadoc @see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see) Agrega un encabezado "Ver también" con un enlace o
> entrada de texto que apunta a una referencia. Un comentario de
> documento puede contener cualquier número de etiquetas [@see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see), todas
> agrupadas bajo el mismo título. La etiqueta [@see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see) tiene tres
> variaciones; la tercera forma a continuación es la más común. Esta
> etiqueta es válida en cualquier comentario de documento: descripción
> general, paquete, clase, interfaz, constructor, método o campo. Para
> insertar un enlace en línea dentro de una oración a un paquete, clase
> o miembro ver [{@link}](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link).

---

Si no se generan los enlaces a todas las clases especificados en el javadoc,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto se debe a su modificador de acceso, puedes configurar para que se generen enlaces con todos los modificadores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma obtendrás enlaces para todas las clases:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me genera el link. Me pone el **See also: `LocalDate`** pero sin link.

Comment: Ah, me parece que es por el modificador de acceso, hay una configuración , que IDE usas?

Comment: Eso pensé, pero estuve mirando en las opciones que aparecen cuando genero el JavaDoc pero no veo nada relevante allí. Uso `IntelliJ Comunity Edition`. El método donde estoy poniendo la anotación es `public static`

Comment: @A.Cedano revisa la imagen donde indico donde configurar, el problema es el modificador de acceso, cambia la configuración y  de esta forma todos los enlaces podrán funcionar.

Comment: Jorge he subido hasta `private` pero aún así no crea los enlaces. Me ha funcionado con *Other Command Line arguments* como sugiere @Sal en su respuesta.